# Why are "to feel" and "to be" only sometimes interchangeable?

Tags: semantics

*I am angry* and *I feel angry* seem to have the same meaning, as do many other *I am **[adjective]*** phrases, like *I am sad*, *I am happy*, *I am ecstatic*.

But *am* and *feel* cannot always be swapped out: *I am weird* and *I feel weird* have different meanings.

How can this be explained?

Comment: Words like angry, happy, sad, and ecstatic describe emotional states. Being weird is not an emotional state.